# JAVA KeyListnener doesnt reack in snake game (JPanel)

Tags: java, key, listener

i cant handle this by myself. I dont have any idea how to get this snake working.
Key listener worked previously (but not always, it worked in ~30% of launches) but now its completly dead. Also, sometimes (not always) when i launch it error shows in my console:

```
Exception in thread "Timer-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at projekt.Plansza.ruch(Plansza.java:92)
    at projekt.Plansza.access$200(Plansza.java:16)
    at projekt.Plansza$Odswiezanie.run(Plansza.java:149)
    at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:555)
    at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:505)
```

And here is code:

```
package projekt;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Plansza extends JPanel{

    private boolean gora = false, dol = false, lewa = false, prawa = true;
    private Klawisz klawisz;
    private ArrayList<Waz> waz;
    private ArrayList<Bonus> bonus;
    private int x = 0, y = 0;
    private int bx, by;
    private int dlugosc;
    private boolean over = false;
    private Image snake;
    private Image jablko;
    private Image tlo;
    Timer czas;
    Random los;


    public Plansza(){
        czas = new Timer();
        Odswiezanie odswiezanie = new Odswiezanie();
        czas.scheduleAtFixedRate(odswiezanie, 1, 100);

        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(800, 600));

        klawisz  = new Klawisz();

        los = new Random();
        bx = (los.nextInt(39)+1)*20;
        by = (los.nextInt(29)+1)*20;

        waz = new ArrayList();
        bonus = new ArrayList();
        Waz w = new Waz(x,y);
        Bonus b = new Bonus(bx,by);

        setFocusable(true);

        dlugosc = 4;

        addKeyListener(klawisz);
        waz.add(w);
        bonus.add(b);
        zaladujObrazki();


    }

    private void zaladujObrazki(){
        ImageIcon iis = new ImageIcon("cialo.png");
        snake = iis.getImage();
        ImageIcon iij = new ImageIcon("jablko.png");
        jablko = iij.getImage();
        ImageIcon iit = new ImageIcon("tlo.png");
        tlo = iit.getImage();
    }

    private void ruch(){

        if(prawa){
            x += 20;
        }

        else if(lewa){
            x-=20;
        }

        else if(gora){
            y-=20;
        }

        else if(dol){
            y+=20;
        }


        Waz w = new Waz(x,y);
        waz.add(w);

        if(waz.size()>dlugosc){
            waz.remove(0);
        }

    }
    private void kolizje(){

        for(Bonus b : bonus){
            if(b.getX()==x && b.getY() ==y){
                b.setX((los.nextInt(39)+1)*20);
                b.setY((los.nextInt(29)+1)*20);
                dlugosc++;
            }
        }

        for(int i = 0; i < waz.size()-1 ; i++){
            if(dlugosc>=5 && waz.get(i).getX() == x && waz.get(i).getY() == y){
                over  = true;
            }
        }

        if(x<0 || y<0 || x>780 || y>580){
            over = true;
        }

    }


    public void paint(Graphics g){

        g.clearRect(0, 0, 800, 600);
        g.drawImage(tlo, 0, 0, 800, 600, this);
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);

        for(int i = 0; i<waz.size();i++){
            g.drawImage(snake, waz.get(i).getX(), waz.get(i).getY(),this);
        }

        for(int i = 0; i<bonus.size();i++){
            g.drawImage(jablko, bonus.get(i).getX(), bonus.get(i).getY(), this);
        }

        if(over){
            czas.cancel();
            g.clearRect(0, 0, 800, 600);
            g.drawImage(tlo, 0, 0, this);
            g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            g.setFont(new Font("TimesRoman", Font.BOLD, 100)); 
            g.drawString("KONIEC", 200, 150);
        }
    }

    private class Odswiezanie extends TimerTask{

        public void run(){
            ruch();
            repaint();
            kolizje();

        }
    }

    private class Klawisz implements KeyListener{

        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
            int klawisz = e.getKeyCode();

            if(klawisz == KeyEvent.VK_UP && !dol){
                gora = true;
                lewa = false;
                prawa = false;
            }

            if(klawisz == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN && !gora){
                dol = true;
                lewa = false;
                prawa = false;
            }

            if(klawisz == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT && !prawa){
                lewa = true;
                dol = false;
                gora = false;
            }

            if(klawisz == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT && !lewa){
                prawa = true;
                gora = false;
                dol = false;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
            //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
        }

        @Override
        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
            //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: What is at line `Plansza.java:92`?

Answer (score 0):

The common problem when a KeyListener doesn't work is because the component doesn't have focus so it doesn't receive the KeyEvent. The common solution is to use `Key Bindings`.

See [Motion Using the Keyboard](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2013/06/09/motion-using-the-keyboard/) for more information and solutions.

Comment: Thank you, but i cant implement this to my game, i mean, i dont know hot to get it works, can you help me?